# Take picture from Gallery And Crop that picture in the selected circle portion In Unity 3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working on a project. I want to take a picture from gallery of android device. 
1. How can i take a picture from gallery of android device?
2. How can i Crop the picture selected circle portion in unity3d?

Comment: 1. http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/android-gallery-on-unity3d.128668/ 2. http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/650732/cut-texture2d-in-circle-format.html Maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code for cropping image. I only pass Texture2D and set centre and radius automatically according to texture; but you can pass them manually if you want to.

```
Texture2D RoundCrop (Texture2D sourceTexture) {
        int width = sourceTexture.width;
        int height = sourceTexture.height;
        float radius = (width < height) ? (width/2f) : (height/2f);
        float centerX = width/2f;
        float centerY = height/2f;
        Vector2 centerVector = new Vector2(centerX, centerY);

        // pixels are laid out left to right, bottom to top (i.e. row after row)
        Color[] colorArray = sourceTexture.GetPixels(0, 0, width, height);
        Color[] croppedColorArray = new Color[width*height]; 

        for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < width; column++) {
                int colorIndex = (row * width) + column;
                float pointDistance = Vector2.Distance(new Vector2(column, row), centerVector);
                if (pointDistance < radius) {
                    croppedColorArray[colorIndex] = colorArray[colorIndex];
                }
                else {
                    croppedColorArray[colorIndex] = Color.clear;
                }
            }
        }

        Texture2D croppedTexture = new Texture2D(width, height);
        croppedTexture.SetPixels(croppedColorArray);
        croppedTexture.Apply();
        return croppedTexture; 
    }
```